# Paginate results of entity reference widget type

Tags: nodes, paging, entities

I have entity reference field with checkboxes/radio as the widget type. The issue is the I have hundreds of nodes and this results in a having a big list. Is there a way to paginate the results or have a "load more" button/link which loads more results via ajax?

I should mention that I tried the entity_view_widget module but had other issues with it and can't really use it for this project.

Comment: Why can't you use autocomplete reference widget instead of checkboxes ?

Comment: The idea is to create a list of nodes and let the users make various selections from the list. Autocomplete widget does not work well with what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice article related to Entityreference Multiselectors [here](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/entityreference-multiselectors).

You can choose one from variety of options mentioned in above article which suggests using of

- Using of [Multiple Selects.](http://drupal.org/project/multiple_selects)
- Using of [Chosen](https://drupal.org/project/chosen)
- An additional possibility is the [Dynamic Multiselect Widget](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_dynamicselect_widget).
- Another option is [Entityreference Views Widget](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget)
- There is [jQuery UI Multiselect](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_ui_multiselect)
- And [Improved Multiple Select](http://drupal.org/project/improved_multi_select)

Hope one of the above works for you :-)

Comment: Thanks Anil for the suggestions! What I'm trying to do is paginate the results and add the ability to filter the results by taxonomy term. Do you if is possible to do that?